# Open file dialog for the server in Eclipse RAP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I have been trying out the `FileDialog` and `FileUpload` in Eclipse RAP. They are awesome to get files from the client. However, in my RAP application I need to export and import files to/from the server's local disk.

Is there any file dialog widget in RAP that would allow me to select a file from a server folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ready-to-use dialog in RAP to select files from the server's file system.

You will need to implement a custom file selection dialog.